# What is my button missing?

Tags: java, android, button, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Ok, so I have been beating my head against the keyboard for about 2 days. 
when I run the program it force closes and log cat tells me a null pointer.
When I put the button in a comment then the program will open.
(Update)
now it runs without nullpointer but the onclick() does not work.
Perhaps its a problem with how I am inflating the button.

Ok so I edited the button and it looks like this now instead,

```
Button b;
    View v1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.current, null);
    b = (Button) v1.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText("Test");
            }

            });
```

But, I think the problem may be with how I am connecting the Tabs in the main xml.

so here is the full part of my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    //final GameEventHandler object = new GameEventHandler();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new 
ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });


    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));

    }
Button b;
    View v1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.current, null);
    b = (Button) v1.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText("Test");
            }

            });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 4 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.current,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        if(dummyTextView.getText().equals("1") ){

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.current,
                container, false);

        }
        if(dummyTextView.getText().equals("2")){
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stats,
                container, false);
        }
        if(dummyTextView.getText().equals("3")){
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory,
                container, false);
        }
        if(dummyTextView.getText().equals("4")){
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.options,
                container, false);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

and here is the xml for the xml that holds the button;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Yesbutton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Yesbutton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RollButton"
        android:text="ok" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nobutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RollButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/okbutton"
        android:text="no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Yesbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/okbutton"
        android:text="Yes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/RollButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/okbutton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Roll" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RollResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/RollButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/RollButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/RollResult"
        android:text="Current Roll:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Welcome to the dungeon! press ok to start!"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="1px" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry if I am not specific enough this is the first time I have had to ask for help.

Comment: Do you have button in `activity_main.xml?`. Pls post the stacktrace and the relevant xml

Comment: Your logcat will give you a line number. I'm guessing it will point to the button part.

Comment: you call the button from an inflated layout. you can point to it, with inflate.

Comment: the button is in fragment layout right ?

Comment: Yes the button is in the fragment layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are doing this - you can't reference a button from within one of the fragments until it has been inflated. I.e. if the button is defined in R.layout.current, this will crash because there is no button present at the time you are calling setOnClickListener. You need to call this later, once you are sure the fragment is inflated.

(I would have put this as a comment but I can't comment yet as I don't have enough rep)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try to inflate it and let you know if it works.

Comment: ok I updated it, I changed how the button is being inflated but now the onclick() doesn't seem to work.